# Power automate: “send an http request to Sharepoint” Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I'm trying to use a Flow to create news links in a modern site when a new post is published to an external site's rss feed.

[image]

It appears to get the JSON content correctly but the "send an http request to SP" action fails with this error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1,
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid
> JSON. The property name '' is not valid. The name of a property cannot
> be empty."}}}

clientRequestId: 2dc5c154-7f82-4e51-aa89-04b4a38ca56a

serviceRequestId: e5c2b09f-10aa-b000-b0cc-529bc8718263

Answer (score 0):

In fact, my test of this API is ok. Judging from the picture, there may be quotation marks and problems in your JSON data, you can use the JSON format check tool to check it.
[image]
JSON for your reference:

```
{"BannerImageUrl":"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/NBA3.png",
              "Description":"test",
              "IsBannerImageUrlExternal":true,
              "OriginalSourceUrl":"http://www.baidu.com",
              "ShouldSaveAsDraft":false,
              "Title":"test title",
              "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.RepostPage"
            }
}
```